# redirect doesnt include path

Tags: java, jetty, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

```
<rule>
    <from>^/asd/(.*)/$</from>
    <to type="temporary-redirect">%{context-path}/?asd=$1</to>
</rule>
```

my website is hosted as `myapp.com/testing` and my jetty context is `dev`

so `myapp.com/testing/dev/`

but when I try `myapp.com/testing/dev/asd/123/`

instead of `myapp.com/testing/dev/?asd=123`

I get redirected to `myapp.com/dev/?asd=123`

I 'm using v 4.0 http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html

Comment: What do you mean "my website is hosted as myapp.com/testing"? What is the "/testing"? The context path is right, you must investigate on what is the /testing part of your application.

Comment: I have local jetty server on port 8080, and my sys admin is redirecting myapp.com/testing to my localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 things mucking about with your request.

Your rewrite filter is at odds with whatever you have in front of Jetty (hardware or software that is converting browser (http client) requests to `myapp.com/testing/dev/` to jetty's `myapp.com/dev/`.  Jetty isn't aware of the extra `/testing/` part of the path, so your rewrite filter cannot add that extra `/testing/` piece for its 302 redirect.

Either you'll need to make the product in front of Jetty smart enough to rewrite the `Location` response header, or you'll need to adjust your rewrite filter to include the extra path information that the product in front of Jetty is aware of.